# Offer Letter declined after giving a salary break up

Tags: salary, job-offer, india

I was interviewing for a position at a major Indian software company. Everything went great and HR collected all documents from me and gave a package that they are willing to offer along with salary breakup on email. I accepted their offer and then they said they would get back to me once offer letter is formally processed in the system.

After one week of silence, when I inquired the HR told me that the package that they were willingly offering was too high and creating discrepancies in their system. What they can offer is much less than what I am currently getting.

I want to know how are offers typically processed. I thought that a company offers a package only after getting approvals, not vice-versa?

What can I do here? Can I hold them accountable for the package they offered me in the beginning?

Comment: Ask yourself if you really want to start working for a company that does not keep its word before you even started. And the usual: without a written offer, you are still in the negotiation phase of the process.

Comment: _I accepted their offer_ What offer? Anything without the offer letter is _not_ an offer..

Comment: @scaaahu at least some of the offer was in writing - this is really a legal Q on breach of contract

Comment: _Can I hold them accountable for the package they offered me in the beginning_ - Are you willing to walk away from their new 'offer' if they don't uphold the original package from the email?

Comment: Legal questions aside, you're getting screwed. It's either a bait & switch or incompetence. Neither one bodes well for a healthy relationship.  Run. Given how difficult it is to change jobs at-will in India, consider yourself lucky you found about them the before actually starting. Think positively and recognize that they did you a favor. If you still really want to work there, meet them in the middle but whatever you do, don't accept the new wage or you'll just show them that you can be pushed around and easily manipulated.

Comment: "What can I do here? Can I hold them accountable for the package they offered me in the beginning?" What if I said, "yes, you can. Just don't ask us to figure out how to do it?" If you can't figure out how to do it, then you just hit your first reality check.

Answer (score -1):

> Can I hold them accountable for the package they offered me in the beginning?

## No.

The point where anybody can be held accountable is when you both have signed the same piece of paper and you both (or at least *you*) have a copy of it. That is called a contract. Anything before is just talk and talk is cheap.

Comment: The bit of paper is not a contract, it is evidence that a contract exists. A verbal agreement is just as binding as a written one. The issue is not that talk doesn't create a contract, the issue is that circumstances don't usually result in evidence of such contract being left afterward.